# Getting unique stores a brand

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 models, *Store*, *Item* and *Brand*. I want to figure out in which stores a given brands items can be found.

I've been trying to create a SQL statement to achieve this, but I can't get near the right result.

Essentially, I want to give the *brand ID* 1, and get a list of stores that have products from this brand.

How can I do this?

Here's my 4 tables:

brand

```
id | name
```

items

```
id | name | brand_id
```

stores

```
id | name
```

stores_items

```
id | store_id | item_id
```

Comment: What have you tried? People here are happy to help fix a problem, but usually not to do the whole work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) your tables. This will return all stores where you can find brand = 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stores.name
FROM
  stores INNER JOIN stores_items
  ON stores.id = stores_items.store_id
  INNER JOIN items
  ON stores_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE
  items.brand_id = 1
```